# exclude private property from print_r or object?

Tags: php, debugging, properties

Basically I am using Code Igniter, and the Code Igniter base class is huge, when I print_r some of my objects they have the base class embedded inside them. this makes it a pain to get the information I actually wanted (the rest of the properties).

So, I am wondering if there is a way I can hide, or remove the base class object?

I have tried

```
clone $object;
unset($object->ci);
print_r($object);
```

but of course the ci property is private.

the actual function I am using for dumping is:

```
/**
 * Outputs the given variables with formatting and location. Huge props
 * out to Phil Sturgeon for this one (http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/09/power-dump-php-applications).
 * To use, pass in any number of variables as arguments.
 * Optional pass in "true" as final argument to kill script after dump
 *
 * @return void
 */
function dump() {
    list($callee) = debug_backtrace();
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $total_arguments = count($arguments);
    if (end($arguments) === true)
        $total_arguments--;

    echo '<fieldset style="background: #fefefe !important; border:2px red solid; padding:5px">';
    echo '<legend style="background:lightgrey; padding:5px;">' . $callee['file'] . ' @ line: ' . $callee['line'] . '</legend><pre>';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arguments as $argument) {
        //if the last argument is true we don't want to display it.
        if ($i == ($total_arguments) && $argument === true)
            break;

        echo '<br/><strong>Debug #' . (++$i) . ' of ' . $total_arguments . '</strong>: ';

        if ((is_array($argument) || is_object($argument)) && count($argument)) {
            print_r($argument);
        } else {
            var_dump($argument);
        }
    }

    echo '</pre>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</fieldset>' . PHP_EOL;

    //if the very last argument is "true" then die
    if (end($arguments) === true)
        die('Killing Script');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for returning only public vars for unknown class:

```
// Get the class of the object
$class_of_object= get_class($object);

// Get only public attributes (Note: if called from within class will return also private and protected)
$clone = get_class_vars($class_of_object);

// Try it
dump($clone);
```

And this is quite hacky, but works - to remove private property from object ( This will not preserve object name ) and of course another drawback is that you need to hard code property name:

```
// First cast clone to array
$b = (array) clone($a);

// Then unset value (There will be null bytes around A and to use them you need to run it in double quotes
// Replace A for * to remove protected properties
unset($b["\0A\0_ci"]);

// Finally back to object
$b = (object) $b;

// Test it
dump($b);
```

Comment: But I want the other private properties, I just don't want that one property

Comment: But `get_object_vars()` expects a object as parameter. `$class_of_object` is a string.

Comment: @TheFox yeah sorry must be typo, should be `get_class_vars()`

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple way that works fine for me:

```
<?php print_r(json_decode(json_encode($object))); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in easily with PHP Reflextion API

```
$myClassName = 'myChildClass';
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($myClassName);

// get properties, only public in this case
$properties = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
//Print all properties (including parent class)
print_r($properties);

//Print properties of desired class only
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    if ($property->class == $myClassName) {
        print_r($property);
    }
}
```

The same thing for methods.

If you really need it - you can create special function to do this work for you and call it when you need such analysis. But I think in most cases good IDE, like my favorite PHPStorm, might do this job for you and when you call class instance - show you only public methods in suggestion list.

Comment: I also use PHPStorm care to add information of how PHPStorm does this for you?

Comment: Well, when you typeing $obj->[ctrl+Enter] it just doesn't show private methods or properties.